# How do i create a tipping program for python?

Tags: python

i am VERY new to programming and i am currently learning python from a book i purchased.
At the end of each chapter it has challenges for you to write programs based on what you have learnt in the previous chapter.It is asking to create a program for a user to enter an amount for a restaurant bill and tells them two amounts a  15% and 20% tip but it has not discussed in the book how to work out percentages in python. I have tried looking online and nothing shows up regarding this. I am sure it is simple to do but i don't won't to carry on further with the book before understanding this.

Comment: Do you know how to get the amount?  Are the amounts integers?  A funny thing to note when using most programming languages is that 1 / 4 = 0, because you are doing integer arithmetic.  That could be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
# input will prompt user for a bill amount at the command line
amount = float(input('Enter the amount of the bill: '))

tip_15 = amount * .15
tip_20 = amount * 0.2

print('A 15%% tip is: %.2f. A 15%% tip is: %.2f.' % (tip_15, tip_20))

print('Total price with 15%% tip is: %.2f' % (amount + tip_15))
print('Total price with 20%% tip is: %.2f' % (amount + tip_20))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bill = raw_input("Please enter restaurant total\n")
print "15 %%: %.2f" %round((float(bill)*.15),2)
print "20 %%: %.2f" %round((float(bill)*.20),2)
```

Comment: This makes sense in parts for example what does raw_input do as opposed to just input. Also why two %% after 15. What does the .2f do..thank you for your patience with me just trying to get my head around it all

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc_tips(total, tip_percentages):
    return [(x, x*total) for x in tip_percentages]

>>> print calc_tips(100, (.15, .2))
[(0.15, 15.0), (0.2, 20.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply by 1.0 in order  to get the value as float

```
amount= 125
tip1 = 15
tip2 = 20

print "tip1=" , (amount * (1.0 * tip1/100))
print "tip2=" , (amount * (1.0 * tip2/100))
```